# I can't seem to import pypdf module

Tags: python, import, pip

I'm new to python, so sorry for newb question.
Im trying to play around with pypdf 3.17.1 but when I try to import the library, or any of its modules, VScode gives me an error squigle under pypdf and informs me:Import "pypdf" could not be resolved.

win 10:
python 3.1.2.0
vs-code + Pylance

installed pypdf in VScode terminal via "pip install pypdf"
sucessful.

ive also uninstalled/re-installed it using
"pip3 install pypdf"

I've never changed any of the install paths, nor used custom paths for any pip installations.
I've verified that pypdf exists in the path location denoted by pip.
I'm a bit stumped as to why it's not finding pypdf when I attempt to import it in myfile.py

[error in VScode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Eyma.jpg)

```
pip show pypdf

Name: pypdf
Version: 3.17.1
Summary: A pure-python PDF library capable of splitting, merging, cropping, and transforming PDF files
Home-page:
Author:
Author-email: Mathieu Fenniak <biziqe@mathieu.fenniak.net>
License:
Location: C:\Users\project68\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:

print(sys.path)
['c:\\Users\\project68\\Documents\\maya\\scripts\python\\CS50P','C:\\Users\\project68\\Documents\\maya\\scripts\\python','C:\\Users\\project68\\Documents\\maya\\scripts\\python\\CS50P','C:\\ProgramFiles\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\python311.zip', 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\DLLs', 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\Lib', 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0', 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\Lib\\site-packages']
```

Comment: That's a warning from VSCode, not an actual python error.  What happens when you actually run the code?

Comment: i though that too, but when I try to intansiate an object, theres no there there.

Comment: "when I try to intansiate an object, theres no there there" -- I have absolutely no idea what this means.  Speaking in riddles is not a good way to get help for technical issues.

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pypdf'

Comment: It seems that you have two (or more) installations of python on your computer, and pip and VSCode do not agree on which installation to use.

Comment: Update the questions with these outputs: the command `pip show pypdf`, especially the `Location` line, and also this code `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Comment: Yes, the problem is exactly as I thought.  You have two python installations on your system.  pip is using `C:\Users\project68\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312`, and VSCode is using `C:\ProgramFiles\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0`.

Comment: I recommend updating your VSCode configuration to use the Python312 installation, and uninstalling the other one.

Comment: @project_68 You mentioned only get this issue with `pypdf`? Let's try a couple others that you don't have for sure. For example: `mpu`, `emoji`, `antigravity`. What happens if you install them?

Comment: Ahh, got it that was it! once I switched the interpreter to the correct version, and ran pip install pypdf again, everything referencing pypdf turned green! many thanks for the trouble shooting and suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Guess #1: Mixed-up Python environments

The problem is most likely that you have different Python versions. You install `pypdf` in a different version than you use.

In such a case, you can run pip through Python:

```
python -m pip install pypdf
```

Your command could also be `python3` or `python3.11` or similar. The rest stays the same.

## Guess #2: VS Code not loading freshly installed packages

> VScode gives me an error squigle under pypdf and informs me:Import "pypdf" could not be resolved [after I installed it]

Try restarting VS code. Give it a few seconds after it started up.

Comment: That worked! thanks so much! my process was: 1. pip ininstall pypdf 2. pip uninstall PyPDF2    3. python3  -m pip install pypdf     Not sure why it worked, but after restarting VScode, all references to 'pypdf' turned green and started working. many thx:)

Comment: You should never have to install `PyPDF2` (I'm the maintainer of `pypdf` and `PyPDF2`). Having both should not cause issues either, though :-) The solution was likely "have you tried turining it off and on again"  Happy coding 

Comment: As John Gordon's responses in my OG question illustrate, the issue was that my VScode was using the wrong interpreter, thx to you both for the help:)

Answer (score 0):

I know you've tried in VScode terminal, but can you enter it in powershell while running as admin? That usually works out for me.
If that doesn't work, try restarting after

Comment: This would be a fine comment, but it isn't an an answer.  However since you posted it as an answer, this question is now marked as "answered" and fewer people will bother to read it.

Comment: My bad dude. I'm kinda new here, so i didn't know. I'll try to do better next time. Sorry.